# How to use regex to restrict numeric?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Code below will accept only numeric on `keypress`. How can I restrict it by range. I want to accept only 12 char.

```
const checkNumber = e => {
      const x = /[0-9]+/g;
       if (!x.test(e.key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
     }
    };

<input
   name="personnelID"
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
   required
   value={form.personnelID}
   onKeyPress={e => checkNumber(e)}
/>
```

Changing to `const x = /[0-9]{12,12}+/g;` does not worked. No `maxLength` please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/^[0-9]{12}$/`.

Comment: @Tushar I can't keyin any key.

Comment: @sg552 have you tried the answer provided ? did that work for you ?

Comment: The issue is the `+` sign in your initial code, you're matching repeating groups of 12 digits. The other problem is that while the answer @Tushar provided is correct, if you check against that every time a user presses a key, they will be unable to type anything unless they directly paste in a 12 digit number right off the bat. You will need to use `/^[0-9]{0,12}$/` to allow typing up to 12 digits, then validate on submit that it is in fact exactly 12. (basically, this does the exact same thing as `maxLength`, there's a reason that property works the way it does)

Answer (score 0):

This restricts digits only:

```
^[0-9]{0,12}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```js
$('input').keypress(function( e ) {    
    var val=String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if(e.keyCode != 8){  // releasing backspace you may add more here
    if(/[0-9]{12,}/.test(this.value) || !/[0-9]/.test(val))
        return false;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="text" value=""   />
```

Comment: _No maxLength please_ at the end of question.

Comment: @Tushar got that now thanks and updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Contact Number</label>
<input name="personnelID" id="subt"  required value="" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" onblur=checknumber(this) style="width: 235px;height: 40px;">
<label id="Invalidmessage" style="color:red;"></label>
<script>
function checknumber(e) {
//var IndNum = /^[0]?[789]\d{9}$/; //this will accept phone numbers of 10-digits starting with 789      
 var IndNum = /^[0-9]{10,12}$/;//this will accept numbers of 10,11,12-digits with in the range of 0-9
 var xx = e.value;
 if (IndNum.test(xx)) {      
        document.getElementById("Invalidmessage").innerHTML = "";           
        return true;
    }
    else {

        document.getElementById("Invalidmessage").innerHTML = "Invalid Mobile Number.";
        e.focus();

    }
}
</script>
```

> Hope this code would be useful.